# Prove that a function is not integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multiple-integral

So the problem is:

> Let $$ f(x,y): [a,b] \times [c,d] \to \mathbf{R} $$ with type
>   $$ f(x,y) = 
> \begin{cases}
> 1, (x,y) \in (\mathbf{Q} \times \mathbf{Q}) \cap ([a,b] \times [c,d])\\
> 0, \text{ else }
> \end{cases} $$
>   Prove that $f$ is **not** integrable in its domain.

So my try at an  answer was by simply taking (letting $R = [x_{i-1},x_{i}] \times [y_{j-1},y_{j}]$ a random cut)
$$ L(P,f) = \sum\sum m_{ij}E_{ij} $$ where $$ m_{ij} = \inf(f(x,y):(x,y) \in R)$$ so 
$$ L(P,f) = \sum\sum 0 E_{ij} = 0 $$ and by that same token 
$$ U(P,f) = \sum\sum 1 E_{ij} = E = 1 $$ and therefore taking into account the Raymond Criterion we get
$$U(P,f) - L(P,f) < \epsilon$$ for $\epsilon = 1/2$
$$1 < 1/2$$ which is a contradiction.

Is my answer correct? What I think I lack is care for the various cases of the domain (if (x,y) is (rational,irrational) or (irrational,rational) or (irrational,irrational)). If they need to be mentioned, how would that need to be written?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $>\epsilon$ not $<$.

Comment: Is the rest correct?

Comment: What is $ E_{ij}$ ?

Comment: The area that's formed by the rectangle of the random cut P.

Comment: Why their sum is equal to 1.

Comment: I think it's because that's the way the function is defined. For pairs of rational numbers, the value of f is 1.

Comment: $ E$ should be the total area $ (b-a)(d-c)$.

Comment: Hmmmm, I see. And the rest of the problem, how would that go?

Comment: You also need changing the value of $\epsilon$.

Comment: To what? I don't really get you.

Comment: I must go. wait for a complete answer. (+1).

Comment: Sure. Thank you in advance.